# Text appearing before animation delay

Tags: css, css-animations

I use the following code for a text reveal animation but the text is already there before the 3 second delay that I declare. How can I fix this?

```css
.header>span {
  animation: slider 3s 3s ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    max-width: 0%;
    border-right: 4px solid #7CDD26;
  }
  99% {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 4px solid #7CDD26;
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span>This is some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need at least `inline-block` (or `block`) to your span element to be able to use `min-width` then you need to add `min-width:0%` initially and add `forwards` to the animation to keep the last state:

```css
.header>span {
  animation: slider 3s 3s ease-in forwards;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
  max-width: 0%;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    max-width: 0%;
    border-right: 4px solid #7CDD26;
  }
  99% {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: 4px solid #7CDD26;
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: none
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span>This is some text</span>
</div>
```